# I cant send mail , mail body contain data taken from database with while loop using php

Tags: php

```
I am trying for send mail using php.Mail body part contain data taken from database with while loop.It shows error.Error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) .Error shown in body part.Ie line $fet['date']; in body part.How i slve these issue? Can i send mail with these body contain html and php code?
```

I am trying for send mail using php.Mail body part contain data taken from database with while loop.It shows error.Error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) .Error shown in body part.Ie line $fet['date']; in body part.How i slve these issue? Can i send mail with these body contain html and php code?

My body part of mail is

```
 $messag=echo "<table width='98%' border='0' 
cellspacing='1' cellpadding='4' align='center' class='greyBorder' >

 <tr class='blueBackground'>
   <td width='4%' align='left' bgcolor='#4096AF'><strong>No.</strong></td>
   <td width='20%' align='left' bgcolor='#4096AF'><strong>Date</strong></td>
   <td width='20%' align='left' bgcolor='#4096AF'><strong>Sale</strong></td>
   <td width='20%' align='left' bgcolor='#4096AF'><strong>Payment</strong></td>   
 </tr>

 $si=1;
 while($fet=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
  {
     $className = ($className == 'evenRow')?'oddRow':'evenRow';

    <tr class='$className'>
       <td class='txt'>  $si;</td>
       <td class='txt'> 
       $fet['date'];    
       </td>
       <td class='txt'> 
       $fet['total'];   
        </td>
       <td class='txt'> $fet['net_amount'];     
       </td> 
    </tr>
    $si=$si+1;
 }

 $className = ($className == evenRow)?oddRow:evenRow;
<tr align='right' class=' print $className'> 
   <td colspan='9'><table width='100%'  border='0' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='0'>

 <tr>
      <td width='50%'  align='center' class='txt'> $pagination </td>           
 </tr>  
 </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>";
```

Anybody give any solution for thee issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong syntex all code is coverd from quotes, so php can't parse it.

Try following code:

```
$message="<table width='98%' border='0' 
cellspacing='1' cellpadding='4' align='center' class='greyBorder' >

 <tr class='blueBackground'>
   <td width='4%' align='left' bgcolor='#4096AF'><strong>No.</strong></td>
   <td width='20%' align='left' bgcolor='#4096AF'><strong>Date</strong></td>
   <td width='20%' align='left' bgcolor='#4096AF'><strong>Sale</strong></td>
   <td width='20%' align='left' bgcolor='#4096AF'><strong>Payment</strong></td>   
 </tr>";

 $si=1;
 while($fet=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
  {
     $className = ($className == 'evenRow')?'oddRow':'evenRow';

    $message .="<tr class='$className'>
       <td class='txt'>  $si;</td>
       <td class='txt'> 
       ".$fet['date']."    
       </td>
       <td class='txt'> 
       ".$fet['total']."   
        </td>
       <td class='txt'> ".$fet['net_amount']."     
       </td> 
    </tr>";
    $si=$si+1;
 }

 $className = ($className == evenRow)?oddRow:evenRow;
$message .= "<tr align='right' class='".$className."'> 
   <td colspan='9'><table width='100%'  border='0' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='0'>

 <tr>
      <td width='50%'  align='center' class='txt'> ".$pagination." </td>           
 </tr>  
 </table>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>";
```

Comment: Again shows the error in the same line.$fet['date'];